# Greatest common length of permutation

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

Given two permutations $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ without their cycle decompositions is there

1. a good method to compute the largest cycle length common between them in their decompositions?
2. a good method to identify no cycle length occurs in common
   between their decompositions?

Comment: What "good" means? Why just computing cycle decompositions is not good?

Comment: Is there a first ordering formulation?

Comment: How, precisely, are you "given" the permutations so that you don't have the cycle decomposition? Do you mean e.g. that you are given it as a map $[1..n] \rightarrow [1..n]$?

Comment: Correct........

Comment: Given two permutations, one cyclic and the other with two cycles of length $n/2$, you can't distinguish them without examining at least $n/2$ values.  This bounds how quickly you can answer your question computationally, and might bound how expressive a logic you need to frame your question in the first place, since local information is never enough.